# How count sum of field value and sort them as per userid using PHP and MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I need some help. I need to calculate the sum of numeric field value as per `userid` and place them into array using MySQL and PHP. I am explaining my table below.

> db_like:

```
id     like    userid

  1       1        10

  2       2        11

  3       1        10

  4       2        11
```

Here I need to count the sum of `like` field value as per `userid` and place the result into array. Please help.

Comment: try something first. Noone is going to sit down and do the whole work for you. You need to try something

Comment: Hint: `SELECT userid, SUM(like) FROM db_like GROUP BY userid`

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT SUM(`like`) AS `likes` FROM [table] GROUP BY `userid`;
```